# cats: random hiss from otherwise sociable cat

Tags: cats, behavior

I have had two new kittens for about a week and a half now, and one of them is generally very friendly to me already, he'll run up to me when I enter the bedroom that I have them in for the time being and meow and start purring when I pet him. However, every now and then, right when I walk into the room, he'll meow a bit, hiss at me exactly once, and then immediately go back to rubbing against me or expressing contentment. I have absolutely no idea why this otherwise friendly cat is hissing at me and then acting as though nothing has happened. Could he be angry that I've gone some time without interacting with him?

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! When did the cat last time saw a vet?

Comment: Maybe just forgot you were friendly? Or you startled him? Not much room in a kitten's head you know. And most of it is filled with bouncing activities.

Comment: How old are the kittens? Where did you get them?

Comment: Hi guys. The cats are about 12 weeks old, and I got them from a shelter. I don't have a date that they last saw a vet, but their foster mom said that they haven't been for any serious sickness, just for vaccinations and to be spayed / neutered.

Comment: "Hey, you startled me -- please don't move so suddenly." I've experienced this exact pattern -- kitten I'd never met before came over to say hello, I moved a bit too quickly to offer a hand to be sniffed, kitten hissed, I left the hand there, kitten decided I was harmless and asked me to play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is likely connected to your kitten still adjusting to his new environment, and to you as a new human! I've fostered many recently rescued cats (or recently left a shelter environment) and they exhibit similar behaviors. A hiss when I first walk in the room and then instantly wanting pets and to play.

In my experience, usually after a few weeks they stop hissing. Kittens typically adjust to new environments more quickly than adult cats so this behavior may wane even faster. But [this graphic](https://static.wixstatic.com/media/a27d24_9e6be05333f941be831261b6d1072802%7Emv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_940,h_608,al_c,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01,enc_auto/a27d24_9e6be05333f941be831261b6d1072802%7Emv2.jpg) is a helpful reminder that it can take cats up to three weeks to settle into a new environment - so at 1.5 weeks it's not alarming your kitten might still be adjusting.

Sometimes hisses aren't out of anger or aggression, they're because the cat is uncertain, so they instinctually give a warning signal. I've always chalked up the hisses that you're describing to being the equivalent of a a knee-jerk reaction. If the hissing is limited to that small window of you first entering the room and your kitten is otherwise friendly and happy, it's likely all that's needed is time! You could try entering the rooms he's in a bit more slowly or to talk before you enter to help the kitten realize it's you - but you may still get a hiss here and there!

Comment: Perhaps it's an anxiety thing. My cat was very anxious when we first adopted her. She showed many symptoms of anxiety, including growling when she heard noises. Yet at the same time, she was friendly with us. I think it took her even longer than three weeks to completely stop with her anxiety symptoms.